# how to create amazon sandbox account

Tags: payment-gateway, amazon-pay

I am working on an MVC core project as a part of self-learning and I want Amazon Pay as the payment option. I am new to the amazon pay and I want to create an amazon sandbox account for testing purposes. I have gone through the documents in the following URL "https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-hosted/set-up-test-account.html".  Then I have created a regular amazon account and tried to create an amazon pay account. For this, I have tried to create a business account using the regular Amazon account.  but couldn't complete the registration process because the "seller amazon" website needs business details, credit card information, etc.

Is this the right way to create an amazon sandbox account or are there any other options?

Answer (score 2):

You need to visit this link - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-onetime/register.html

It Says "To get started quickly, you can also create a developer account that can only access the Sandbox environment and complete registration later: US, EU (French, German, Italian, Spanish), UK, JP."

Click on US/UK and register. This should create a sandbox account.